# Gephi and integrated security with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, gephi, mssql-jdbc

I use `gephi 0.9.2` on Windows. I can connect to my SQL Server (2016) via `File - Import Database - Edge List` entering all parameters incl. username and password in the gui (this means connection via SQL Server authentication). I would like to connect to the database using integrated security ("Windows authentication"). I cannot find a way to enter the connection string or to give that information in any other way.

Is there any way in gephi 0.9.2 to define the connection string to a SQL Server directly?

This would do the job perfectly:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://server\instance;databaseName=DBName;integratedSecurity=true;
```

All I could find is a binary file "EdgeListDatabase" in my roaming profile. But this seems to only hold the data entered in the gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how the connection is established (no other way than over the Edge List):

[gephi/io/importer/plugin/database/ImporterEdgeList.java](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/blob/6eb5eba177648428a08a62c8d86da53f645eb7c8/modules/ImportPlugin/src/main/java/org/gephi/io/importer/plugin/database/ImporterEdgeList.java#L109-L114)

```java
private void importData() throws Exception {
    //Connect database
    String url = SQLUtils.getUrl(database.getSQLDriver(), database.getHost(), database.getPort(), database.getDBName());
    try {
        report.log("Try to connect at " + url);
        connection = database.getSQLDriver().getConnection(url, database.getUsername(), database.getPasswd());
        report.log("Database connection established");
    }
```

This is how the connection string is formed by getUrl from the fields you pass in the Edge List:
[gephi/io/database/drivers/SQLUtils.java](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/blob/6eb5eba177648428a08a62c8d86da53f645eb7c8/modules/DBDrivers/src/main/java/org/gephi/io/database/drivers/SQLUtils.java#L61-L70)

```java
public static String getUrl(SQLDriver driver, String host, int port, String dbname) {
        String res = "jdbc:";
        res += driver != null ? driver.getPrefix() : "";
        res += "://";
        res += host != null ? host : "";
        res += ":";
        res += port != 0 ? port : "";
        res += dbname != null ? "/" + dbname : "";
        return res;
    }
```

That's how to final connection is established in the SQLServerDriver:
[gephi/modules/DBDrivers/src/main/java/org/gephi/io/database/drivers/SQLServerDriver.java](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/blob/6eb5eba177648428a08a62c8d86da53f645eb7c8/modules/DBDrivers/src/main/java/org/gephi/io/database/drivers/SQLServerDriver.java#L67-L76)

```java
public Connection getConnection(String connectionUrl, String username, String passwd) throws SQLException {
        //Bug #745414
        if (!connectionUrl.contains(";databaseName=")) {
            String dbname = connectionUrl.substring(connectionUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            String url = connectionUrl.substring(0, connectionUrl.lastIndexOf('/'));
            connectionUrl = url + ";databaseName=" + dbname;
        }

        return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, username, passwd);
    }
```

[`public static Connection getConnection(String url, String user, String password)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

You might be able to make an injection over the host field if you set the host to:
`server\instance;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=javakerberos;password=`
You will bypass a syntax error from the inserted `res += ":";` if you use it as *password=:*
Set the dbName as usual, leave port blank and set a dummy username and password.

Now you have to hope that the driver doesn't overrule the windows authentication, because you called getConnection with credentials.

If this doesn't work, your only way is to change the source of the [ImporterEdgeList.java](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/blob/6eb5eba177648428a08a62c8d86da53f645eb7c8/modules/ImportPlugin/src/main/java/org/gephi/io/importer/plugin/database/ImporterEdgeList.java#L109-L114) plugin to call [getConnection(String url)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-) and manually forge the url based on database.getHost() if the colon bypass doesn't work.

Something like that:

```java
private void importData() throws Exception {
    //Connect database
    String url = "jdbc:";
    url += driver != null ? database.getSQLDriver().getPrefix() : "sqlserver";
    url += "://";
    url += database.getHost();
    try {
        report.log("Try to connect at " + url);
        connection = database.getSQLDriver().getConnection(url);
        report.log("Database connection established");
    }
```

With this hack you can specify the rest of the connection string over the host variable

Comment: Thank you for that hack! I had to change three things: 1. host must be "[Servername as FQDN];instanceName=[as given];integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=nativeauthentication;password=:" (without ") 2. port 1433 (standard) 3. putting the sqljdbc_auth.dll in the path. Now everything is fine. Thank's again